# Cannot Find the Correct Working Directory in Python Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, spyder

I'm having trouble with the working directory in Spyder console. I'm trying to convert an xlsx file into a pandas array, but I keep getting the same error. I've changed the `Run` Directory in preferences and it should be the correct one.

[screenshot of Spyder console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCxXr.jpg)

Sorry if this is a really newbie question I just really dont know where to go from here.

Comment: That address bar in the upper right of the spyder window sets your working dir. You're in `../python_work/__pycache__` right now.

Comment: Or for double-checking: ```import os; cwd = os.getcwd()```. For your task: why not using absolute paths?

Comment: Thank you for your comments and your help. Should the current working directory be the file folder that both the excel file and the python file are in? because even when I change the cwd to `../python_work` (the folder both files are in) I still get the same message. And is the red text with the run file and cwd always supposed to pop up? Again sorry I'm new to both Pandas and Spyder

Answer (score 6):

The path at the top right of the screen in Spyder will change the working directory of the IPython console. Set it to the desired working directory. Hit Ctrl+F6 to check the run configuration of your script and make sure it is set to run at the current work directory. See if that fixes the problem.

As others have mentioned, the os module provides a way of getting and changing the working directory directly through python, rather than changing the working directory settings in Spyder. Your second option is to do the following before importing the .xlsx file:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/mypath') # Change your working directory to your .xlsx file location
```

The other useful os function to check what your current directory is:

```
os.getcwd()
```

As for your current case, there isn't any issue. The `runfile('', wdir='')` text is simply letting you know which .py script you are running and for what working directory. There isn't any other output, because you haven't set anything to happen after you read the excel file to xls_file. Try adding a `print(xls_file)` statement to the end of your script and it should print the pandas DataFrame to the console.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no error after you change your directory in the `Run` menu. `runfile` is the function used by Spyder to run a file in the IPython console. You are simply not getting any output after `runfile` because you're not printing anything. If you add the command `print(xls_file)` at the last line of your file, then you'll see the output.

Answer (score -1):

You can always read a file giving the full path. From [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) doc.

```
excelSheet = pd.read_excel(io="C://..//myfile.csv")
```